# PIXI.js - scrolling background grid

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, pixi.js

In the game [agar.io](https://agar.io), there is a grid background, and It scrolls with the player as they move. In PIXI.js, how would I go about recreating this? Preferably, in an efficient way that does not waste resources by rendering off-screen grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `PIXI.extras.TilingSprite` class, created for the purpose of  rendering repeatable patterns, tiles, etc. The class uses only one quad (two triangles) for the whole pattern, repeating is achieved in the fragment shader.

Here is a working example: http://pixijs.io/examples/#/basics/tiling-sprite.js

Here is documentation: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.extras.TilingSprite.html

Answer (score 3):

`TilingSprite` documentation / example has changed:

Example: https://pixijs.io/examples/#/sprite/tiling-sprite.js

Documentation: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.TilingSprite.html